# How to make rang for color in java?

Tags: javascript, java, android, colors

I want to type a 6-digit-number (RGB-hex) and then click on a button to show the color's name. I did not find color lib in java to give me arbitrary colors' names.

**So what I do is :**
I found this lib in javascript [this is the **ntc js lib**](http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/) and tried to re-implement it in java , so I defined a hash map and put each value with the name for example :

`sColorNameMap.put("B43332", "Well Read");`

The code runs ok when given the same key which I put in the hash map, for example when I write the value B43332 then I get **Well Read** as name of color.

**My problem:** When I enter a value not equal to the key I pushed then I can not get the name of color.

**What I need :** I need a function to return the name of the closest matching color. I tried to understand how ntc does it but I couldn't.

For example the value `B23634` is not pre-defined in **ntc js lib** BUT it resolves to give the name **Well Read** , like this picture :
[image: here I enter number not predifined and the number close to the closet color name]
So any help to implement a function returning the closest value (6 digit of number) to a certain color is appreciated.

Comment: Depends on what you mean with `closest matching color` color. The RGB value is actual a point in a 3 dimensional space, so you could calculate the distance in that space, e.g. like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/calculate-distance-in-3d-space). But that will most of the time not give you the color that is visually the closest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the *closest matching color* as the one closest in the 3 dimensional RGB space, you can use something like this:

(check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/calculate-distance-in-3d-space) for information on how to calculate that distance)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> sColorNameMap = new HashMap<>();

    String rgbCode = "B23634";

    String colorName;
    if (sColorNameMap.containsKey(rgbCode)) {
        colorName = sColorNameMap.get(rgbCode);
    } else {
        colorName = nearestColor(rgbCode, sColorNameMap);
    }

    System.out.println("colorName = " + colorName);

}

private static String nearestColor(String code, Map<String, String> sColorNameMap) {

    int[] rgb = getRgb(code);

    double nearestDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    String nearestNamedColorCode = null;

    for (String namedColorCode : sColorNameMap.keySet()) {
        int[] namedColorRgb = getRgb(namedColorCode);
        double distance = calculateDistance(rgb, namedColorRgb);
        if (distance < nearestDistance) {
            nearestDistance = distance;
            nearestNamedColorCode = namedColorCode;
        }
    }

    return sColorNameMap.get(nearestNamedColorCode);

}

private static int[] getRgb(String code) {

    int r = Integer.parseInt(code.substring(0, 2), 16);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(code.substring(2, 4), 16);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(code.substring(4, 6), 16);

    return new int[]{r, g, b};

}

private static double calculateDistance(int[] rgb1, int[] rgb2) {

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(rgb2[i] - rgb1[i], 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(sum);

}
```

If you have some other metric for *closest matching color*, it is just the matter of changing the implementation in `calculateDistance()` method.